# Anyone know why this Javascript Async Function is failing 1% of the time?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, audio, html5-audio

Thought I had this little routine nailed that would load Javascript Audio asynchronously but it fails every great once in awhile. Any idea what the issue could be? It seems to be ok if I repeatedly hit refresh but if it runs for awhile and then I hit refresh the screen will go blank and I don't see the "Sounds async load complete." pop up in the F12 console.

```
export default class Chant {
  static bundles = {};

  constructor() {
    if (this instanceof Chant) {
      throw Error('Chant is a static class and cannot be instantiated.');
    }
  }

  static addBundle(bundle, sources) {
    this.bundles[bundle] = sources;
  }

  static async loadBundle(bundleKey) {
    const audios = {};
    const bundle = this.bundles[bundleKey];
    for (const key in bundle) {
      audios[key] = await this._loadAsync(bundle[key]);
    }
    delete this.bundles[bundleKey];
    return audios;
  }

  static async _loadAsync(src) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const audio = new Audio(src);
      resolve(audio);
      audio.onerror = () => { reject(`Invalid audio source: ${src}`); };
    })
  }
}
```

And it's called like this:

```
import Chant from '/js/modules/chant.mjs';

// global variables
let sounds;

async function loadAudioAsync() {
  // sounds
  Chant.addBundle('sounds', {
    spinner: 'assets/sounds/spinner-0.ogg',
    horn: 'assets/sounds/party-horn-0.ogg',
    pop: 'assets/sounds/pop-0.ogg'
  })
  sounds = await Chant.loadBundle('sounds');
  console.log('Sounds async load complete.');
}

async function init() {
   await loadAudioAsync();
}

windows.onload = () => {
   init();
}
```

Comment: perhaps an `audio.onerror` triggers? use try/catch in `loadAudioAsync` to determine the error

Comment: `oncanplaythrough` doesn't return anything; not sure why you'd `return audio`; the `resolve(audio)` does what you need. Besides that, there's nothing obviously wrong; could just be the fact that you're refreshing too often and you're exhausting resources on the server.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks for the input. Made some changes based on your insight.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yep it doesn't fail now. Thank you! Updated the code.